Unit test case failed using jest in angular
I am trying to create unit test case for the below code,

export class TestService {  
  currentContent$ = this.getContent().pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged((p, c) => isEqual(p, c))
  );

  constructor() {}

  getContent(): Observable<string> {
    // Does its working and return value
    return of('some test return value');
  }
}

The test case written for this code is,
it('should emit values from currentProductPath$ only if they are not deeply equal', (done) => {
      // Mocking testMethod to emit a series of values
      const mockData1 = {value:'Path1'};
      const mockData2 = {value:'Path2'};
      const mockData3 = {value:'Path3'};

      jest.spyOn(service, 'getContent').mockReturnValue(of(mockData1,mockData2,mockData3,mockData3));

      // Emit some mock values
      const emittedValues: any[] = [];
      service.currentContent$.subscribe((value) => {
        emittedValues.push(value);
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        expect(emittedValues).toEqual(['Path1','Path2','Path3']);
        done();
      }, 0);
    });
  });

After executing this test case, an expected result should be ['Path1','Path2','Path3'], but it is coming as an empty array. Seems like, this block of code is not getting executing.
testService.currentContent$.subscribe((value) => {
    emittedValues.push(value);
});

I am not sure, where I am writing it wrong. If I write the same code from service into method like below,
testMethod():Observable<string>{
  return this.getContent().pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged((p, c) => isEqual(p, c))
  );
}

And replace currentContent$ with testMethod() in test case file then test case will execute as expected. Not sure why this is happening. Please help me with this.

As per my searching, we can not modify value for the currentContent$ dynamically because, it is declared before the constructor and will execute once in a lifetime of the service.  The code which executes once like the code in constructor or the code defined like currentContent$, we can not write unit test case for those code.
